# Stored Ligature HTML is not rendering

Tags: html, special-characters, ligature

I am using GroupDocs Viewer to take a PDF and create a HTML page for it. I store the HTML in a nvarchar(MAX) field in my SQL2012 database. I just learned today during some testing that we're having some special characters (ligatures) in the documents not rendering correctly.

Question Marks are highlighted only to make them easy to find.

[image]

These Ligatures(ﬂ, ﬁ, ﬀ) are missing for some reason. I checked my database and they seem to be stored there correctly.

I checked the JsonResult server method I'm using to load the page and I'm getting some mixed results trying to determine if my pageHtml string has the char.

```
public async Task<JsonResult> LoadDocument(int contentID, int page)
{
    try
    {
        var documentPageData = await APIAccess.Get<DocumentPageUserData>(DocumentPageData.GetDocumentPageRoute, contentID, CurrentUser.UserID, page);

        JsonResult result = new JsonResult()
        {
            ContentEncoding = Encoding.Default,
            ContentType = "application/json",
            Data = new
            {
                pageHTML = documentPageData.DocumentPage.PageHtml //.Replace("?", "fl").Replace("?", "fi").Replace("?", "ff")      //Don't like this idea
            },
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
            MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue
        };

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(string.Format("There was an error loading the page.\r\n\r\nDetails:\r\n{0}", ex.Message),
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

When I mouse over DocumentPage.Html and ask to render it as HTML, it looks great. The Text Render has a `<span>?</span>`however. Not sure if that's just because the Text Render doesn't have a font or if there is another problem.

[image]

On the Client side I store the html text in session storage until the page is requested then I render it into a div like so.

```
 var externalHtml = sessionStorage.getItem(currentPage);
 $('.viewer').text('');
 $('.viewer').append(externalHtml);
```

I've tried checking the network traffic and the client side html but it looks like it has ? so I'm not sure where I'm loosing my characters. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like the preview inside your IDE is using a different font than your output (serif vs. sans-serif, respectively). What font should the output be using? Is it readily available on your PC or included in the CSS?

Comment: Good Catch. I'm not sure Group Docs Viewer is embedding the fonts when it creates the html from the pdf. My PDF is sans-serif, but I can't tell if the font matches exactly to what I'm rendering incorrectly. Problem is I just can't pick a specific font and include it since I need to have the font that the user used in the PDF.

Comment: checking the network tab for that area and the span looks like \u003cspan \u003e?\u003c/span\u003e Seems to imply it's a question mark before trying to render it. Maybe the server needs the font?

Comment: Maybe that, or the network tab doesn't have the correct font to render it either. Can you get the output as a byte stream to confirm; maybe through Wireshark?

Comment: Bytes: ef ac 81. That's what's between <span></span>. Wireshark is rendering it as <span>...</span>. I looked it up and a period is a non-printable byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JsonResult was not being encoded properly. I changed `ContentEncoding = Encoding.Default`  to `ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8`. After that it rendered perfectly. Sigh... Been working on this for 2.5 days.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out :)